# In how many ways can 12 people consisting of 6 men and 3 women can be seated as men can only sit in pairs.

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can 12 people consisting of 6 men and 3 women can be seated as men can only sit in pairs. this question is bothering me a lot and still trying to get around with it but nope! irritating.

Comment: 12 people consisting of 6 men and 3 women?

Comment: 6+3=9, somethings off

Comment: 3 genderless people.

Comment: When you say "men can only sit in pairs", do you mean there can't be one man between two women anywhere, and at the same time there cannot be three men in a row?

Comment: yes there can't be women between two men but there can be 3 men in row and even 6 as far as they are in pairs. And yeah there are 9 people in total instead of 12!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you meant 6 women,  you have $\binom{6+3}{3}$ seat allocations. For each such allocation you have 6!  women allocations and $\frac{6!}{2!2!2!}$ possible pairs of men.

Comment: ah am sorry for annotating the wrong question. so here it is: There are 6 men while 3 women who have to sit on a round table while the restriction is; men have to sit in pairs. So how many ways they can be arranged thus they fulfill the restriction?

Comment: If they are seated around a table, you need to account for the fact that 'rotating' all of them simultaneously leads to the same allocation

Comment: but what if men have to sit in pairs? and they can sit in a row

Comment: yeah but if you have e.g. MFMFMFFFF, for each rotation of this sequence around the table you get the same sequence as all M and F are unique